# Docker compose share environment variables

Tags: docker, environment-variables, containers, docker-compose

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db1:
    [...]
    healthcheck: ..

  db2:
    [...]
    healthcheck: .. 

  service1:
    [...]
    links:
      - db1:dbname 
      - db2:dbname
    depends_on:
      db1:
        condition: service_healthy
      db2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

However, the main service `service1` fails because it's looking for the environment variables from the databases,

```
${env.DBNAME_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR}
${env.DBNAME_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT}
${env.DBNAME_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE}
```

I know the compose docs state "Environment variables are no longer the recommended method for connecting to linked services. Environment variables will only be populated if you’re using the legacy version 1 Compose file format." but there's not much I can do here without them.

What is best practice here? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few thoughts on this one:

- Links are relatively deprecated in favor of DNS based service discovery. You'll still want to use `depends_on` to maintain startup order.
- Environment variables have only gone away in a limited aspect with `docker stack deploy`. Since you're on version 2.1, it's clear you're using `docker-compose`. Even then, the part of environment variables that is going away for `docker stack deploy` is the ability to expand environment variables from the host into the yml file, not from the yml file into the container. And even with that expansion gone, you can use `docker-compose config` as a preprocessor to generate a yml that can be used with `docker stack deploy`. That's a long way of saying don't change your design for this limitation.
- Since I recommended against linking, a good replacement for the two databases coming in with the same name on the network is a network alias.
- I'm assuming you defined two databases like this to map to separate volumes/filesystems or constrain to separate hosts, etc. Otherwise, scaling the instance would let you make a single definition.

The result would look like:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db1:
    [...]
    healthcheck: ..
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
         - dbname

  db2:
    [...]
    healthcheck: .. 
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
         - dbname

  service1:
    [...]
    environment:
     - DBNAME_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: dbname
     - DBNAME_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT: 3306
     - DBNAME_ENV_MYSQL_DATABASE: yourdb
    depends_on:
      db1:
        condition: service_healthy
      db2:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: Just one clarification: aren't stacks still experimental?

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic Stacks have been out of experimental for a while now. Defining a stack with a `docker-compose.yml` has been GA'd since 1.13.0 released in January.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got something wrong about understanding how does the `docker-compose.yml` file work.

The first issue I see is that you have added the same alias `dbname` to two links, `db1` and `db2` in your `links` section of the `service1` service. The part after the semicolon is the alias. You do not have to use it.

Also, when you use linking there is no need to add the `depends_on` section, linking includes it implicitly. Further more, the `condition` is removed from version 3 of the file format.

As for your question, here is what I usually do when linking containers.

First, in your application, make your connection string is parametrized based on your environment variables. Depending on your programming language/tools this might be simple or not. For the sake of simplicity, imagine you can parametrize your connection string like this (example from Play Framework):

`connectionString=jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}`

In Play Framework this means that the `DB_HOST`, `DB_PORT` and`DB_NAME` should be read from the environment variables. Your framework probably has similar or alternative constructs.

Now, properly link the services in the docker-compose file

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db1:
    [...]
    healthcheck: ..

  service1:
    [...]
    links:
      - db1:database1
```

However, this is not enough. It would be if you have written `database1` instead of `DB_HOST` and hardcoded the port and database name in the application configuration. That is also acceptable, but I like to make my application configuration as independent as possible from the platform. That's why I set up parts of the configuration to be read from the environment variables (not to mention, this approach plays nice with Docker :-) .

Some environment variables take the value of a link alias or link itself, like the `DB_HOST: database1`. This might look redundant, but keeps the application separated from the deployment, IMHO.

In the end, my service would look something like this:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  db1:
    [...]
    healthcheck: ..

  service1:
    [...]
    links:
      - db1:database1
    environment:
      - DB_HOST: database1
      - DB_PORT: 5432
      - DB_NAME: accounting
```

You can use the same approach with multiple databases.

Comment: Thanks! One question, what should I use in place of `condition` in v3? I need the health checks to maintain the startup order which is why I stuck with 2.1